# Using a cell reference in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy a range from a filtered table to another sheet.  The starting point is easy however I would like to only copy a number of rows down based on a cell that a user enters into.  I can make it work when I hard code the number however I would like to make this based on a cell.

The variable lastrow is where I need to have the cell H4.  (H4 in my spreadsheet is where the user keys in the number of rows to copy)

My code thus far is:

```
Sub Line()

Dim Copyrange As String
Dim lastrow As Range

Startrow = 8
lastrow = 10
Let Copyrange = "B" & Startrow & ":" & "H" & lastrow
Range(Copyrange).Select
End Sub
```

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Does anyone use `Let`anymore? I haven't since the 1980s. Just write `Copyrange = ...`. The `Let` is optional, and really it only adds clutter.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like all you need is this?

```
Let Copyrange = "B" & Startrow & ":" & "H" & Range("H4")
```

Comment: Thank you Mattboy.  Now that it works I have found the next problem in that it is a filtered table and I only want the first "x" number of rows that are shown after filtering "H5" at the moment it copies the first number of rows regardless if they are filtered or not.

Answer (score 0):

Changing my answer to the following instead. Not the best of solutions, as working with SpecialCells is tricky at best, but this might suit your needs fairly well.

```
Sub Illusion()

Dim Source, Dummy As Worksheet
Dim SRow, LRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ThisWorkbook
    Set Source = .ActiveSheet
    Set Dummy = .Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
End With

SRow = 8
LRow = Range("H4").Value + 1

'Change the H10000 below to the correct end row of your unfiltered table.
Source.Range("B" & SRow & ":H10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

With Dummy
    'We create an illusion that we copy only the names we need by bridging using a dummy sheet and copying from there.
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .Range("A1:A" & LRow).Copy
    'Paste to desired location as values as well.
    .Delete
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

What I did here was, we copy the visible cells into a dummy sheet, adjust the number of names to copy from that dummy sheet and do whatever you want with it, then delete the dummy sheet. It's a quick and dirty, but it beats having to go to the intricacies of SpecialCells.

Comment: Hi, Not sure what I have done wrong but when I use your code I receive the error Compile Error:  Syntax Error?????  I did a copy and paste  What did I do wrong??

Comment: What I have is a list of employees that will be regularly exported from another system.  I attach a random number to each one and then sort by this number and select the top "number" of rows based on the sample size.  I then want to copy this range to another sheet as values that can then have our logo and other things added and then printed.  In short it is a random employee list generator.

Comment: Changed my answer above. Please see if it somehow addresses your query.